# CNAME in Google Cloud DNS

Tags: dns, cname, google-cloud-dns

I have been trying to add the `www.mydomain.net` alias to `mydomain.net`. I already have a MX record and NS and SOA records auto-added by Google.

I am getting cnameResourceRecordSetConflict error:

> Error code "cnameResourceRecordSetConflict" : The resource record set
>   'entity.change.additions[0]' is invalid because the DNS name
>   'mydomain.net.' may have either one CNAME resource record set or
>   resource record sets of other types, but not both.

I understand the advice the error gives me, but how can I have other records then? I need MX and CNAME both on my domain.

Comment: I too have this need yet google cloud DNS docs are out of date and fail to match their admin web console pages ... doc is at https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/setting-up-dns   ... Please let us know how you solved this issue

Comment: To accomplish both www.mydomain.net and domain.net pointing to the same record, I added another A record with the DNS name of www.mydomain.net. Seems fairly obvious now that I look back on it :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem you're having is an issue with the [rules of DNS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034), which forbid a CNAME record where another record exists.

> If a CNAME RR is present at a node, no other data should be
> present; this ensures that the data for a canonical name and its aliases
> cannot be different.  This rule also insures that a cached CNAME can be
> used without checking with an authoritative server for other RR types.

You are trying to create a CNAME for the `@` record. The `@` record is the origin, so example.com for instance. There are already at least two records at the origin, the SOA (start of authority - basically information about the domain) record, and an NS (name server)

For this reason you can't create a CNAME record for the Origin.

For this reason you can only create an A record for the origin (in order to fulfill a standard A record query - of course you can still create MX etc). However there are some DNS providers that have a special type of record an ANAME if you need a CNAME record at the origin you would need to switch to one of those.

Comment: So in Cloud DNS I cannot use a CNAME with a top-level domain?

Comment: @Lightheaded because you should not do that

Comment: @danius When I want to use cloud run with a managed domain, then I have to use it no?
I dont see any way around here besides migrating back to my former DNS provider who allowed me to do that.

Comment: @F.Tepel well the RFC is for something and then each provider decides how to follow (or not) it. The regular way to go is creating an A record for the www domain

Answer (score 2):

I've currently had the same issue while configuring my GCP Cloud DNS domain.

The error is very generic and not super clear. However, I found an issue on GitHub at [kubernetes-sigs/external-dns](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns/issues/740) with the title ***"Google-CloudDNS: Unable to write CNAME record when txt registry is enabled."*** which made it a bit clear what other record could be causing the issue.

Google's DNS [error message documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/error-messages#cnameresourcerecordsetconflict) mention that `SOA` and `NS` would be conflicting with `CNAME`:

> **cnameResourceRecordSetConflict**
> *The resource record set `entity.change.additions[XX]` is invalid because the DNS name example.com might have either one CNAME resource record set or resource record sets of other types, but not both.*
> This error occurs when you create two types of resource record sets, such as both an A record and a CNAME record for the same DNS name. A common cause of this error is trying to create a CNAME record at the zone apex. This is not possible because it would conflict with the required SOA and NS records of the same name.
> Recommended action: Pick one or the other.

However, it doesn't feel right as both `SOA`, and `NS` records are added automatically when creating a Cloud DNS service.

Looking back to my Cloud DNS, I found two `TXT` records I added for validation of property with Google, and once I removed the `TXT` records, I was able to add the `CNAME` record.

I hope it helps future developers.